# Error while moving HTML form from jsp to ThymeLeaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to follow this as reference [Serving Static content in SpringBoot](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content)

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;

/**
 * Created by Eric on 11/25/2015.
 */
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/appPage")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("title", "Best Of the App");
        model.addAttribute("basecontext", "Best Of the App");
        return "appPage";
    }
}
```

My HTML form being below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${title}" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
<input type="hidden" type="text" id="basecontext" value='${basecontext}'/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to set value in hidden input field. But that gives me error

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="appPage", line 9 - column 33

I am trying to move this html page which was getting loaded in a JSP application to Spring Boot + ThymeLeaf.

If I simply place this content in **index.html** without a Context handler in Controller. the page is loaded just fine. Thymeleaf does not throw any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThymeLeaf uses xml and not html and you are not allowed to have attributes of the same name in xml `type="hidden" type="text"`

You actually should get `SAXParseException: Attribute "type" was already specified for element` in your spring log

Comment: thanks varren. I too found the issue, but could not get the reason behind it. What you mentioned answers it correctly and makes sense.